# Getting a point from a point, length and angle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, pythagorean-triples

Using the diagram below, if we know the coordinates 'point A' and 'point B' as well as side lengths a,b,c. Is it possible to get the exact coordinates for points D & C that would also function as expected if sides a and b are not of equal length

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZUX6.jpg

**EDIT: Solved, thanks for the proof example David K. So simple in practise :)**

Comment: As drawn, triangle $abc$ appears to be a right-angled triangle (in which case the three sides are not of equal length).  Can you clarify if it's right-angled or not please?

Comment: If you just know the coordinates of $A$ and $B$ you can find coordinates of $C$ and $D$. Use the figure for proof #4 here: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/#4 making sure that the sides of the outer square are parallel to your coordinate axes.

Comment: Sorry, it is right angled